# Marking specific buffer lines in vimscript

Tags: vim

I need my plugin to visually mark certain lines within the active buffer (the criteria behind which lines are marked is irrelevant here).

Is there any way to do this in vimscript?

By "visually mark" I mean changing the background color, or having some kind of margin with different colors for marked and unmarked lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use signs.  See `:h signs` for details, or a plugin like this for an example:

https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter